# I don't seem to get notifications on the Area 51 discussion-zone

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, area-51, notifications

I posted [a question](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1044/shouldnt-we-add-everything-circus-related-to-this-proposal) on the Area 51 discussion zone. And apparently someone posted an answer on that question, but I didn't get any notification of that. I just saw it by coincidence.

Is this a bug? Or just not supported?

Comment: Are you referring to the notifications in the StackExchange dropdown in the upper left, or the envelope? And on which site the notifications missing?

Comment: @Emmett: Well... I'm thought it was both, but apparently, when I'm looking now in my inbox in the StackExchange dropdown, I see an entry for the answer I received, but I didn't see the envelope light up.

Comment: Damn, I'm bumping my head here. When I look in my recent activity on the Are51 discussion site, I also see an entry for the answer I received. I could swear I didn't see it at the time. Anyway, this must have been a glitch in the matrix or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The envelope no longer lights up when someone answers your question. This functionality was [removed a while back](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68387/the-envelope-icon-driving-me-mad-with-false-positives/69680#69680) so as not to duplicate inbox notifications.

Additionally, the envelope notifications for Area 51 and the Area 51 Discussion Zone are completely separate.

You should, however, receive [inbox](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/new-global-inbox/) notifications on *all* sites when someone answers your question in the Discussion Zone.